# No Python, há algum jeito além de `numpy` e `float('nan')` de obter a constante especial `nan`?

Tags: python

Estive lendo o site do [Underhanded C Contest](http://www.underhanded-c.org/), em que o objetivo é escrever código sutilmente malicioso, que pareça normal a primeira vista. Uma das técnicas comuns mencionadas foi o uso de *not a number*, ou `nan`, constante que tem algumas propriedades especiais; notavelmente, qualquer tipo de comparação com `nan` resulta em `False`.

Pensando em uma prova de conceito em Python, cheguei no seguinte:

```
def maior_que_10():
    entrada = input('Digite um número: ')
    try:
        entrada_float = float(entrada)
    except ValueError:
        print('Erro!')
        return
    if entrada_float > 10:
        print('Maior que 10!')
        return
    elif entrada_float <= 10:
        print('Não é maior que 10!')
        return

    print('Inesperado!')

while True:
    maior_que_10()
```

A função corretamente trata de valores numéricos inválidos emitindo um erro e ao olhar desatento, parece nunca chegar ao `print('Inesperado!')` porque verifica `> 10` e `<= 10`, mas ao ter a entrada "nan" executa a última linha:

```
Digite um número: 11
Maior que 10!
Digite um número: 9
Não é maior que 10!
Digite um número: 10
Não é maior que 10!
Digite um número: foobar
Erro!
Digite um número: nan
Inesperado!
```

Teoricamente, em código menos trivial, poderia esconder-se código malicioso depois dos dois `if`. Isso, porém, depende de se ter uma entrada do usuário passada pro `float`.

**Existe alguma operação entre variáveis que gere um `nan` de outro modo?**

Pensei em divisão por zero ou raiz de número negativo, mas resultam em exceções, e não `nan`:

```
>>> math.sqrt(-1)
 ValueError: math domain error
>>> 1/0
 ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Existe alguma operação entre variáveis que gere um nan de outro modo?

No final da documentação do módulo math do Python você encontra:

> A NaN will not be returned from any of the functions above unless one
>   or more of the input arguments was a NaN;

Ou seja - em geral não. Mas é possível você chegar a um NaN, por exemplo se tentar subrair float.inf de float.inf - só que nesse caso seu problema passa a ser gerar o  `float.inf`:

```
In [100]: a = float("inf")                                                                               

In [101]: a - a                                                                                          
Out[101]: nan
```

Uma outra forma é escrever é anotar a forma binária de um "nan" como um objeto do tpo bytes, ou um número inteiro - e usar o módulo "struct" para converter esses bytes de volta num ponto flutuante, que então será um NaN:

```
 struct.unpack("d", struct.pack("Q", ((2 ** 12 - 1) << 52) + 1))[0]
```

Ou usando ctypes:

```
In [199]: import ctypes                                                                                  

In [200]: class A(ctypes.Union): 
     ...:     _fields_ = [('i', ctypes.c_uint64), ('f', ctypes.c_double)] 
     ...:                                                                                                

In [202]: A(i=((2 ** 12 - 1) << 52) + 1).f                                                               
Out[202]: nan
```

Answer (score 5):

(* relendo a questão inteira, vi que escrevi uma resposta extensa sobre como verificar uma entrada de ponto decimal, mas que não responde bem a sua pergunta específica - desculpe. Vou manter a resposta por que pode ajudar iniciantes que caiam aqui por conta do título da pergunta)

Em versões mais recentes do Python é possível fazer `from math import nan` - isso coloca no namespace a variável `nan` que contém um número `nan`.

Em versões mais antigas (anteriores à 3.5 do Python), o recomendado era colocar no seu código:

```
nan = float('nan')
```

mesmo (ou usar a expressão `float('nan')` diretamente.

Além disso é importante ter em mente ao lidar com NaN's que um valor NaN nunca é igual a outro, quando comparado com `==` (nem igual a si mesmo). A melhor forma de saber se um valor é um NaN é usar a função `isnan` do módulo math:

```
from math import nan, isnam

isnan(nan)
```

imprime `True`.

Dito isso sobre NaNs - há mais coisas a considerar sobre o uso de `float` direto em cima de uma string que o usuário digita.  Em particular, valores infinitos podem ser expressos com `float('inf')` (e infinidade negativa com "-inf"), e também são aceitos números com notação científica, em que um fator expoente de "10" pode ser adicionado ao número depois da letra "e":

```
In [95]: float("1e3")                                                                                    
Out[95]: 1000.0
```

Então, se você quer relamente limitar a entrada a números positivos ou negativos, com pontos decimais, é melhor fazer o "parsing" dos mesmos com mais cuidado do que simplesmente chamar `float(entrada)`.

Em geral, quando falamos em "fazer o parse", muitas pessoas pensam primeiro em expressões regulares. Eu considero que expressões regulares são de díficil leitura e manutenção, e as pessoas tendem a colocar expressões simples, que não correspondem à todas as possibilidades de dados.

## verificando o dado digitado com expressões regulares:

Python é uma boa linguagem para expressões regulares por que felizmente não inventaram de misturar as mesmas com a intaxe da linguagem - você chama funções normaizinhas e passa uma string com a expressão regular que quer comparar com o seu texto - há várias funções no módulo `re` de expressões regulares - por exemplo para "encontrar todas as ocorrências" (`re.findall`) ou substituir (`re.sub`). Nesse caso, queremos simplesmente ver se uma expressão casa com a entrada do usuário.

E na pressa alguém poderia pensar "quero verse o usuário digitou um ou mais dígitos, seguido de um ponto opcional, seguido de um ou mais dígitos" - essa expressão pode ser escrita como `"[0-9]+\.?[0-9]+"`  - basta olhar pra isso e ver que não está bom: e se o usuário digitar um sinal de "-"? E se houver apenas um dígito? (a segunda parte espera mais um dígito depois do ponto - apesar do ponto ser opcional) - resultado - enquanto que essa expressão pode casar com "11", "23.2", "0.1", não vai casar com "1", "-1", ".23", etc...

PAra encurtar a história, a expressão regular que verifica um número decimal, com sinal opcional, com pelo menos um dígito válido, ou nenhum dígito se houver ponto decimal, e se houver ponto decimal pelo menos um dígito depois dele é:

```
c = r"-?(?:[0-9]+|(?=\.))(?:\.[0-9]+)?$"
```

(A documentação de regexps em Python está aqui - https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html )

E você poderia fazer no seu código:

```
import re

def maior_que_10():
    entrada = input('Digite um número: ')
    if not re.match(r"-?(?:[0-9]+|(?=\.))(?:\.[0-9]+)?$", entrada):
        print('Erro!')
        return
    entrada_float = float(entrada)
    ...
```

## Verificação da entrada com código Python

Então, em nome da legibilidade, e saber o que se está fazendo, pode valer a pena usar as funçẽos de manipula~ao de string do Python: split, find, 
 count,  isdigit  para fazer uma função que verifica se uma string é um decimal bem formatado antes de tentar converte-lo em float.

Dá pra fazer algo do tipo:

```
verifica_decimal(text):
   if not text:  # string vazia
      return False
   filtered = text.replace('-', '').replace('.', '')
   if not filtered.isdigit(): # há caracteres que não são nem dígito nem - nem .
       return False
   if '-' in text[1:]: # sinal 'perdido' no meio do número.
       return False
   if text.count('.') > 1 or text[-1] == '.': # Mais de um '.', ou '.' na última casa
       return False
   return True

def maior_que_10():
    entrada = input('Digite um número: ')
    if not verifica_decimal(entrada):
        print('Erro!')
        return
    entrada_float = float(entrada)
    ...
```